# Use any other element as label for a checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Is there a possible way to use any other HTML-Element as a label for a checkbox. I would like to set the bootstrap `list-group-item` with same functionality as the label for my checkbox.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<body>

  <ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item">
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label style="width: 100%;">
                <input type="checkbox" id="cb.1.0" value="1.0">Answer
            </label>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>

</body>
```

my suboptimal workaround was to set the labels width to 100%, but I guess there must be better working solution for this simple problem

Comment: Just stick with label it can be styled to any appearance, you will need javascript if you wish to have text "Answer" to be clickable without label.

Comment: what higher level problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to have the input element inside your label element, you can give your checkbox an id, and give the label an attribute `for="checkbox-id"`. Then the label can be wherever in the tree you want it to be.

Comment: I know, but the bootstrap `list-group-item` can't be wrapped with a label, so this isn't practicable for this problem

Comment: you don't need to wrap it with the label, you can just put the label somewhere else in the markup separately and the `for` attribute will connect it to the input element.

Answer (score 0):

I think that without breaking semantics the only option you have is to simplify and combine a little bit:

```html
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <label class="checkbox" style="width: 100%;">
      <input type="checkbox" id="cb.1.0" value="1.0">Answer
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

But that's about it. You can't use another element as a label and it's not semantic to use a label instead of an `li`.